# Can't set uniform value in OpenGL shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I am trying to get simple shaders to work. To be more specific, **I am trying to set a uniform value of the shader**. The shaders compile successfully and work correctly if I eliminate the uniform value. Here is the (vertex) shader code:

```cpp
#version 440 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;

uniform mat4 mvp;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertex, 1);
}
```

And the code I use to set the value (`glGetUniformLocation` returns 0 as expected):

```cpp
mvp = glm::mat4(
    glm::vec4(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f)
);

GLuint matrix = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvp");
glUniformMatrix4fv(matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to set the value at all. If I query the uniform's value using `glGetUniformfv`, it returns the default value (not the one I just set), and the geometry doesn't show up at all (but that is just a consequence, that's not the problem here).

If I hardcode the uniform's value in the shader, the application displays the geometry correctly, and when asked for the value (again, using `glGetUniformfv`), it returns the correct value.

```cpp
#version 440 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;

uniform mat4 mvp = mat4(
    vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f)
);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertex, 1);
}
```

Any idea why does this happen? I am using OpenGL 4.4, but I have tried many different versions with the same result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you calling `glUseProgram` before setting the uniforms? A full working listing can be found in many examples online, including what I had written sometime back ([Github: `sgxperf/sgxperf_gles20_vg.cpp`](https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_gles20_vg.cpp)) that shows the sequence to be:

> ```cpp
> glCreateProgram()
> glAttachShader()
> glLinkProgram()
> glUseProgram()
> glGetUniformLocation()
> glUniformMatrix4fv()
> ```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you. I did not realize that I have to call `glUseProgram` before setting the uniform, but it actually does make sense.

Comment: and `glUseProgram()` and `glGetUniformLocation()` could actually be swapped, right?

Comment: No, because glUseProgram sets the correct state first, and glGetUniformLocation relies on that state to get the location of the uniform.

Comment: @mlvljr I think they can be swapped, since glGetUniformLocation takes the program to be queried as first parameter, so it *can* be queried without being used first. (Also experimenting confirms this.) The documentation doesn't say anywhere the program should be used before query.