# OpenGL 2D projection matrix issue

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, glm-math

I have a simple vertex array that draws a quad to the screen.

```
glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

// Load shaders

...

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 0.0f, 
    0.0f, 0.0f, 

    0.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 0.0f
};

GLuint vao, vbo;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

...

glUseProgram(program);
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "spriteColour"), colour.x, colour.y, colour.z);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Using the below simple vertex and fragment shaders.

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 vertex;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}

#version 330 core
out vec4 color;
uniform vec3 spriteColour;
void main()
{    
    color = vec4(spriteColour, 1.0);
}
```

This works exactly how I expect. It renders a rectangle to the upper right corner of the window.

Now I want to add a simple model and projection matrix. I am using an orthographic projection matrix and my model matrix just scales the quad to 100 x 100.

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, (GLfloat)screenWidth, (GLfloat)screenHeight, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

...

glm::mat4 model;
model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(100.0f, 100.0f, 1.0f));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

...

// Update vertex shader
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 vertex;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I would expect this to render a 100 x 100 quad at the top left of the screen however I don't see anything.

I can only assume that somehow my transformations are causing the quad to be drawn off screen and clipped? I am pretty new at Open GL so I am not entirely sure what is wrong here. I've been over it numerous times and based on the tutorials I am using (http://learnopengl.com/) it seems correct.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I've done wrong?

Comment: What happens if you remove projection matrix from position calculation? And what is shader in `glGetUniformLocation(shader, "projection")`?

Comment: Try @Mars suggestion to rule out any issues with wrong projection matrix.  you should still see tha same output,  since your screen will be - 1,1 and 0-100 quad should look the same.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to activate the program before setting uniforms.

[Can't set uniform value in OpenGL shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967506/cant-set-uniform-value-in-opengl-shader)